# C# syntax ignoring a parameter, asking of possibilities

Tags: c#, syntax, parameters, optional-parameters, named-parameters

Having

```
public static void Search(string name, int age = 21, string city = "Tehran")
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Name = {0} - Age = {1} - City = {2}", 
        name, age, city));
}
```

I want to call Search method using name and city parameters to keep the default value of age.

AFAIK parameter should be referred by name

```
Search("Mahdi", city: "Mashhad");
```

I want to know if it is possible to make the call without specifying value for age and also without calling city by name? I mean something like jumping over a parameter, something like :

or

```
Search("Mahdi",,"Mashhad");
```

I've seen almost similar behavior for `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) { some code; }
```

or any other syntax that matches the case?

Comment: No, it's not possible. `for` loop does not accepting any parameters - this behavior is not similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
public static void Search(string name, string city = "Tehran", int age = 21)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Name = {0} - Age = {1} - City = {2}", 
        name, age, city));
}
```

Now you can use it as

```
Search("Mahdi", "Mashhad");
```

> Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list,
>   after any required parameters.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: No I meant rational Idea :) argumentative with that meaning. Among all the answers this one is more logical, less code and everything in its place. Thanks.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari i just missunderstand it because of my english skills, im glad that helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Simply create an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which takes two string parameters like this:

```
public static void Search(string name, string city)
{
    Search(name, 21, city);
}

public static void Search(string name, int age = 21, string city = "Tehran")
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Name = {0} - Age = {1} - City = {2}", 
        name, age, city));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Search("Mahdi", "Mashhad");
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating default value you can call `Search(name, city: city)`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I considered that, but unless you change the parameter names also, that would result in an infinite recursion.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think the compiler is smart enough to catch that, it does not enter the recursion at all.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari Well, I tested this code using `Search(name, city: city)` inside the first overload, and yes, it did result in recursion. However if you change the name of the `city` parameter in the first overload then it works fine.

Comment: @p.s.w.g yep, you are right - I didn't notice self call here

Comment: @p.s.w.g yeah didn't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nullable int for `age`. Like this:

```
public static void Search(string name, int? age = null, string city = null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Name = {0} - Age = {1} - City = {2}", 
        name, age ?? 21, city ?? "Tehran"));
}
```

Then you could call the following combinations:

```
Search("Mahdi");
Search("Mahdi", 20);
Search("Mahdi", null, "Cairo");
```

which would use `age=21` and `city="Tehran"` for the default values.

Comment: looks good but if we do this then what's the point of optional parameters?

Comment: If all the arguments are non-optional, you would have to supply all three parameters all the time. Like: `Search("Mahdi", null, null );`